# Write a query to find out how many times a particular movie category is rented. Arrange in descending order

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to answer the above question but I'm unable to get the output as, Name of category | Number of times the category was rented.

My code is below,

```
select c.category_id, sum(r.rental_id) as Rental_count
from category c
inner join film_category fc on fc.category_id = c.category_id
inner join film f on f.film_id = fc.film_id
inner join inventory i on i.film_id = f.film_id
inner join rental r on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
group by c.category_id, c.name
order by Rental_count desc
```

[image]

Comment: Please share sample data, and the expected output for that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, count(rental_id) as Rental_count
from category c
inner join film_category fc on fc.category_id = c.category_id
inner join film f on f.film_id = fc.film_id
inner join inventory i on i.film_id = f.film_id
inner join rental r on r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
group by c.category_id, c.name
order by Rental_count desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name as Name, count(rental_id) as Rental_Count
from category 
inner join FILM_CATEGORY
using (category_id)
inner join FILM
using (FILM_ID)
inner join inventory
using (FILM_ID)
inner join Rental 
using (inventory_id)
group by name
order by count(rental_id) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [answer]. In particular, it's always best for your code to be accompanied by an explanation of how yours solves the problem, especially when there are existing similar answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
select Name,count(rental_date) as Rental_count    
from category inner join film_category using(category_id)
        inner join film using(film_id)
        inner join Inventory using(film_id)
        inner join Rental using(Inventory_id)
group by category_id,Name
order by Rental_count desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it